# Asp.net OnClientClick show value from other cell in table

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, repeater

I have the following ASP Repeater in a table:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPage" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptPage_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rptPage_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td id="ArticleTitle">
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"AuthorName") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="edit" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID") %>' Text="Edit" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="return fnConfirmDelete(this)" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID") %>' Text="Delete" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="<%# String.Format("/news/Article={0}", processTitle(Eval("Title"))) %>">View Here</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This all works fine.

There is a confirm button on the delete function, using the following method:

```
function fnConfirmDelete(ArticleTitle) 
    {
        return confirm("Delete Article " + ArticleTitle);
    }
```

Now, what I want to do is pass the text from this:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title") %>
```

into the confirm box.

I have tried adding a 'name' field:

```
<asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="return fnConfirmDelete(this)" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID") %>' Text="Delete" name='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title") %>'/>
```

But this does not display the text in the name field, but some kind of server side change.

I have also tried passing the value into the JavaScript function:

```
<asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="return fnConfirmDelete('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title") %>')" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID") %>' Text="Delete" />
```

But this says the server tag is not well formed.

I have also tried to pass in an id from the cell that has the value, but again server tag is not well formed.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Also, once I get it to the JavaScript function, how would I retrieve the value?

EDIT:

I tried:

```
 <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="return fnConfirmDelete('"<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title") %>"')" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID") %>' Text="Delete" />
```

as suggested by @Reddy below, but it also gave a server tag not well formed error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when using a repeater, the repeater assigns a value to the name field, so anything I store there gets overwritten with the assigned name field.

So instead, I stored the variable in the `title`, which now displays as intended:

```
<asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" title='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title") %>' OnClientClick="return fnConfirmDelete(this)" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID") %>' Text="Delete" />
```

EDIT:
Then I can retrieve the element using JQuery as follows:

```
function fnConfirmDelete(ArticleTitle) 
{
    return confirm("Delete Article: " + $(ArticleTitle).attr('id'));
}
```

One issue, for some reason, JQuery could not retrieve the element 'title' eg:

```
    return confirm("Delete Article: " + $(ArticleTitle).attr('title'));
```

But if I rename the field to `LinkTitle` it all worked fine:

```
<asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" LinkTitle='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title") %>' OnClientClick="return fnConfirmDelete(this)" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID") %>' Text="Delete" />

return confirm("Delete Article: " + $(ArticleTitle).attr('LinkTitle'));
```

Which is just a custom field name

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in your OnClientClick, change to this.

```
OnClientClick="return fnConfirmDelete('"<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title") %>"')"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# "return fnConfirmDelete(" + Eval("Title") + ");" %>' 
CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID") %>' Text="Delete" />
```